# Hibernate Table doesn't exist error

Tags: java, hibernate

I really need your help.

I'm new t hibernate. Trying to save an object but all the time i'm getting error:

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernate.person' doesn't exist

Here is domain object:

```
@Table(name = "Person")
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "Person_age")
    private int age;
    @Column(name = "Person_name")
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here is my hibernate config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">******</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Show all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping class="ua.macko.domain.Person" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The error i am getting is: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernate.person' doesn't exist`.

I was trying to set hbm2ddl.auto parameter to create and to update but that gave me no result.

Please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Thnx in advance

Comment: Try <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> instead of <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

Comment: I tried this thing too. Didn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate's 'hbm2ddl.auto' property with value 'create' is not re-creating table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778755/hibernates-hbm2ddl-auto-property-with-value-create-is-not-re-creating-table)

Comment: @macko, check the complete logs and see if hibernate was able to create the table successfully, I guess hibernate had some issue in table creation itself.

Comment: @Chaitanya, it doesn't create the table and i don't know why

Comment: @macko, then there should be some error in logs while table creation itself. Please update your question by adding the complete log details.

Comment: After adding javassist library the issue has been solved. Thanks to all for help!

Comment: Bit old, but do the user you are using have the privileges to create a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding javassist library the issue has been solved. Thanks to all for help!

Answer (score -1):

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Is wrong for `hibernate.cfg.xml`, use

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

instead.