# hbm2ddl.auto is not working

Tags: hibernate

I have created one entity class Emp, I am using hbm2ddl.auto to create tables, below entity related table is creating properly, but before this table in my database some more tables are there, if i use property hbm2ddl.auto as create it need to drop the total schema(total tables) and created the entity related table freshly, old tables are not deleted. That tables are there and this new table is created, I am not getting this create functionality can anyone please clarify my doubt. I used the version 3.6.4.

## Emp.java

```
@Entity

@Table(name="Employe")

public class Emp {

    @Id

    int empid;

    String ename;

    public int getEmpid() {

        return empid;

    }

    public void setEmpid(int empid) {

        this.empid = empid;

    }

    public String getEname() {

        return ename;

    }

    public void setEname(String ename) {

       this.ename = ename;

    }

}
```

## configuration.cfg.xml

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password">sun</property>
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<mapping class="in.hib.Emp" />
```

My main program is this

```
public class HibApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Emp e=new Emp();

        e.setEmpid(2);

        e.setEname("pavai");

        Configuration cfg=new Configuration().configure();

        SessionFactory sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory();

        Session session=sf.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(e);

        session.getTransaction().commit();        

    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate's 'hbm2ddl.auto' property with value 'create' is not re-creating table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778755/hibernates-hbm2ddl-auto-property-with-value-create-is-not-re-creating-table)

Answer (score 0):

Dear there are four possible values which can be used with hbm2ddl.auto all four are defined below

1. validate- it simply checks that table and its columns are existing in database or not an if a table does not exist or any column does not exist than Exception is thrown.
2. create - If the value is create than hibernate drops the table if it already exist and then creates a new table and executes the operation, this is not used in real time as the old data is lost from database.
3. update - If the values is update than hibernate uses existing table and if the table does not exist than creates a new table and executes operation. This is mostly and often used in real time and it is recommended.
4. create-drop - if the value is create-drop than hibernate creates a new table and after executing the operation it drops the table, this value is used while testing hibernate code.

Thanks
Njoy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

instead of

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```